# How to read post string in go via gin-gonic

Tags: go, curl, go-gin

This might be a stupid question, but I just cannot wrap my head around to get this from documentation.
Please help

So, I want client to send POST request like this

curl -X POST localhost -d "heheheh"

this is not json or any encoding but a simple string
How can I read this via gin-gonic ?

Thanks

Comment: try https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.GetRawData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solves it

```
str, err := c.GetRawData()
```